# Trouble installing android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After downloading the Android Studio installer from the website and running it.

I then get these error messages:

[image: The first message that pops up]

then

[image: The second message that pops up]

I have Java installed as well, but the most recent version of java that I got off of the website only came with a jdk and not a jre. But, I have seen videos of people running java with only the jdk and after running javac on my computer it works fine there.

I have googled a few answers and none of them have works and I'm considering reimaging my computer again. I have tried a method using regedit and system file checker tool recently and both haven't done the trick. I have had this issue for a while so I can't remember all of the fixes I have tried.

If anyone could be of assistance it would be a great help.

Comment: This all started after I reimaged my computer the first time from windows 7 to windows 10 due to a major issue with my computer that prevented it to run. Before that it ran perfectly fine.

Comment: You need to post the messages inside your question, not as a link.

Answer (score 0):

From the error popups it seems that you are trying install 64 bit android studio setup on 32 bit window system. Please check then download 32 bit version and try installing it.

Comment: I thought that was the case too so I checked what bit version of windows 10 do I have and it says x64 so that's what really stumped me.